# How do I make my closing remarks in a letter one line in LaTex?

Tags: letters

My closing remarks appear on two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=black,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Singapore Botanic Gardens\\ 1 Cluny Road\\ Singapore 259569}
\opening{Dear Dr.~Nura Abdul Karim and Ms.~Serena Lee,}
\vspace{0.25cm}


I am looking forward to this unique opportunity. Please feel free to reach out to me with questions or concerns.

\vspace{0.25cm}
\closing{Thank you for your time and consideration,}

\vspace{0.25cm}
\encl{Curriculum vitae}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

The width of the `\closing` is set by the length `\indentedwidth`. You can set this to be the `\textwidth`:

```
\setlength{\indentedwidth}{\textwidth}
```

And the closing will fill the line.